# onHover effect with textarea

Tags: jquery

I am trying to  create an hover effect, so when a user moves his mouse over a button, a textarea will be displayed below the button where the user can insert text before submitting a form. If the user leaves the textarea after it was was opened, I would like it to be closed again.... The problem with the code I've used below is that once the user leaves the button area (in order to insert text in the textarea) the textarea disappears. Help would be appreciated!

I have used the following code (You can find the following example also at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifiso3) ):

**CSS**

```
#send-container {
  position:relative;
}
#text-container {
  display:none;
  background-color:#FEF9F4;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top:28px;
  left:0;
  padding:2px;
}
  
textarea {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  resize: none;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="send-container">
    <input type="button" value="Button">
    <div id="text-container">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$("#send-container").live("mouseenter",
            function() {
                $("#text-container" , $(this)).show();
            });
      $("#send-container").live("mouseleave",
            function() {
              $("#text-container" , $(this)).hide();
            }
       );
```

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one instance you can increase the height of the #send-container.

```
 $("#send-container").live("mouseenter",
        function() {
            $(this).css('height', 200); // or whatever it will work with your design
            $("#text-container" , $(this)).show();
        });
  $("#send-container").live("mouseleave",
        function() {
          $(this).css('height', 100); // revert to original height
          $("#text-container" , $(this)).hide();
        }
   );
```

This increases the area your listener, will listen too :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, consider whether or not this is the best approach to what you're trying to achieve. It seems as this will provide a horrible user experience. Firstly, does the 'button' also submit the form? If so, the textarea will disappear when it's clicked, as the user would have left it.

Here's an example of what you've asked for, but it's impossible to submit the form:
http://jsbin.com/otuvu4/edit