# Hover effect with button and textarea

Tags: jquery

(I've posted a similar question before but now it is more targeted..)

I am trying to create a special hover effect with jQuery. I have a submit button - when a user moves his mouse over it I want a `textarea` element to open below the button. The user can then move his mouse into the `textarea` and type something... When he finishes he can move his mouse back to the submit button and submit the form. If the user moves his mouse outside of the `button`+`textarea` then the `textarea` should disappear.

The effect is basically identical to a navigation menu when a user places his mouse over a menu item, a list of related items opens below the item and the user can then choose from them. If he leaves the area, the related items list closes.

You can find a test I've made with no success at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifiso3) (the `textarea` disappears whenever the user tries to reach it)

**HTML**

```
<div id="send-container">
    <input type="button" value="Button">
    <div id="text-container">
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS (jQuery)**

```
$("#send-container").live("mouseenter",
            function() {
                $("#text-container" , $(this)).show();
            });
      $("#send-container").live("mouseleave",
            function() {
              $("#text-container" , $(this)).hide();
            }
       );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onHover effect with textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959887/onhover-effect-with-textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a height on the container, at the moment it isn't high enough to include the box.

Once you've done that, you seem to still have a problem with keeping it there, you might want to add something to ensure that on focus it's still there.

Comment: The problem is that the textarea should be floating (because there should be elements below the send-container). This is the reason the text-container has position:absolute;